# Create new objects based on shared property in previous array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

I have an array of objects containing a "year" key and a "date" key like so:

```
    var fullDates = [
{ 'year': '2018', date: '2018-01'},
{ 'year': '2017', date: '2017-02'},
{ 'year': '2016', date: '2016-03'},
{ 'year': '2018', date: '2018-04'},
{ 'year': '2017', date: '2017-05' },
{ 'year': '2016', date: '2016-06'}
];
```

I want to make a new array of objects containing the year and the dates but where the "date" key is an array like shown below. How can i do this?

```
var final = [
{ 'year': '2018', date: ['2018-01', '2018-02']},
{ 'year': '2017', date: ['2017-03', '2017-04']},
{ 'year': '2016', date: ['2016-04', '2016-06']}
]
```

Comment: And what have you tried?! where's your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [group objects in array based on value of key in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838686/group-objects-in-array-based-on-value-of-key-in-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` operation to get that output:

```js
var fullDates = [
  { 'year': '2018', date: '2018-01'},
  { 'year': '2017', date: '2017-02'},
  { 'year': '2016', date: '2016-03'},
  { 'year': '2018', date: '2018-04'},
  { 'year': '2017', date: '2017-05' },
  { 'year': '2016', date: '2016-06'}
];
var final = fullDates.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
  var existingObj = acc.find(item => item.year === obj.year);
  if(existingObj){
    existingObj.date.push(obj.date);
    return acc;
  }
  obj.date = [obj.date];
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(final);
```

Comment: hehe, same approach. beaten by 2min :). The only difference is that i don't change current object.

Comment: @fredd5229 glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce`.

For each year, create an `object` containing `year` and `dates` properties  and for each repeating `year` add `date` in the `array`. Then get all the values from this `object` accumulator.

```js
const fullDates = [ { 'year': '2018', date: '2018-01'}, { 'year': '2017', date: '2017-02'}, { 'year': '2016', date: '2016-03'}, { 'year': '2018', date: '2018-04'}, { 'year': '2017', date: '2017-05' }, { 'year': '2016', date: '2016-06'} ],
    result = Object.values(fullDates.reduce((r, {year, date}) => {
      r[year] = r[year] || {year, dates : []};
      r[year].dates.push(date);
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
    var fullDates = [
{ 'year': '2018', date: '2018-01'},
{ 'year': '2017', date: '2017-02'},
{ 'year': '2016', date: '2016-03'},
{ 'year': '2018', date: '2018-04'},
{ 'year': '2017', date: '2017-05' },
{ 'year': '2016', date: '2016-06'}
];



const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => {

    let yearData = accumulator.find(x => x.year == currentValue.year);
    if(yearData !== undefined){
        yearData.date.push(currentValue.date);
    }
    else{
        accumulator.push({ 'year': currentValue.year, date: [currentValue.date]});
    }


    return accumulator;
}


var final = fullDates.reduce(reducer, []);
```

Comment: Your approach will need to know all the keys of the object in `fullDates` as you are creating a new object so that will add complexity if there are many properties in object.

Comment: That is absolutely true.